# C++ if(!cin) causes loop

Tags: c++, cin

I tried to use if(!cin) to validate if the user input really is an integer. However my programm then just goes into an infinite loop never asking vor new input

```
do{
    cin >> temp->data;
    if(!cin){
        cout << "Please enter a Number!" << '\n';
        correct=false;
        }
   }while(correct==false);
```

Would be great if someone could help me :)

Comment: you need to clear the stream's error condition. but better separate the tasks of reading a line and parsing it.

Comment: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/istream-and-ignore.html read this

Answer (score 3):

When std::cin fails to read the input, the appropriate error flags are set. Therefore you want to reset the flags using std::cin.clear() so that the next input operation will work correctly and then skip everything until the new line using std::cin.ignore(..) in order to avoid similarly formatted input.

```
while (!(std::cin >> temp->data))
{
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        std::cout << "\nPlease enter a number!" << std::endl;
}
```

`std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max()` returns the max amount of characters a stream can hold so that the whole line is guaranteed to be ignored.

Comment: our solutions are pretty close, but I'm not really sure whether seelenkuchen really intended to skip the first prompt...

Comment: " Please enter a number! " feels like an error message in case the user did not enter a number as expected. Otherwise there are many ways he can go about it, either by writing another std::cout outside the loop, by using logical operators or using a break like in your answer.

Comment: Your operator precedence is broken in your test I think. `!` before `>>`, right?

Comment: You are correct. In fact I was just doublechecking operator precedence.

Comment: I just noticed the "!" in his message, assuming that there should be no first prompt, deleting my answer in favor of yours.

Comment: `10000` should be `std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max()` in `ignore`. Sure it's unlikely the line is longer than 10000 chars, but using `max` is a special case and guarantees that the length parameter is ignored and the stream will keep discarding until it hits the delimiter. If it's too long winded you can always create a `constexpr` alias.

Comment: @seelenkuchen Just take note that you may want to handle the case where the user sends an eof signal.

Answer (score 0):

Use `cin.fail()` to check whether the user entered correct input. `cin.fail()` returns `true` if the last `cin` command failed, and `false` otherwise. Moreover, your loop is likely to be infinite, so you must also state an `else` where you will set the check flag `correct` to `true`. Thus, to invalidate the loop's condition and exit the loop in the case user entered correct input (see code below):

```
do{
    cin >> temp->data;
    if(cin.fail()){
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(10000, '\n');
        cout << "Please enter a Number!" << '\n';
        correct=false;
     } else {
        correct=true;
     }
}while(correct==false);
```

Comment: move the `correct = false` to a declaration/initialization before `do` and just make the test `} while (!correct);`

Comment: How is OP going to learn anything from this when you paste in corrected code with no explanation?

Comment: This is a really obfuscated way to go about input.

Comment: @Veritas Verum quidem dicis.

Comment: @Veritas as your name says, you are speaking the truth. Nevertheless, the OP didn't ask for the most elegant and efficient way to go about input. He asked why his loop goes infinite.

Comment: I won't argue. Just saying that it's good to promote cleaner code.

Comment: `cin.fail()` is identical to `!cin` , some argue it is less idiomatic

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do that kind of check, read the data from `cin` to a `string` and convert the `string` to a number:

```
string str;
do{
    cin >> str;
    if(!cin){
        cout << "Please enter a Number!" << '\n';
        correct=false;
        }
    else{
        istringstream stream(str);
        stream >> temp->data;
        if(!stream){
            cout << "Please enter a Number!" << '\n';
            correct=false;
        }
     }

   }while(correct==false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your 'correct' variable actually doesn't do anything the way you are using it. It's not possible to exit the loop without `correct` being true; so you could do away with it, and just use a loop-exiting command when you have read the number.

Also, none of the answers posted so far handle the input being closed. They would go into an infinite loop in that scenario.

```
// A loop; we will break out when we successfully read a number.
while ( 1 )
{
// Prompt for a number and read it
    cout << "Please enter a Number!" << endl;
    cin >> temp->data;

// Exit loop if we successfully read
    if ( cin )
         break;

// Check to see if we failed due to the input being closed
    if ( cin.eof() )
    {
        cerr << "End of input reached.\n";
        return 0;   // depends what your function returns of course
    }

// reset the error condition that was caused by trying to read an integer and failing
    cin.clear();

// discard anything they previously typed
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
}
```

Moving on from this, a good design would be to actually have this code be an entire function in itself. Then you can call the function whenever you need to get a number safely, without needing to duplicate code. The function declaration might be:

```
void input_number(int &the_number, std::istream &in, std::string prompt);
```

which would output `the_number`, and it would handle end-of-file either by throwing an exception, or by relying on the caller to check for `!cin`, or even by returning a `bool`; whatever fits in best with your error handling overall.

Comment: The ignore member function stops at eof regardless of the character specified.

Comment: @Veritas one would hope so. Is that relevant to something I posted?

Comment: Just saying that I don't understand your reasoning for getting stuck in an infinite loop in the case of eof when there is no input indirection involved.

Comment: Your post and 40two's post both get stuck in an infinite loop when `cin.eof()` happens. The only way for your loop to exit is if a number is successfully read, and that can't happen after eof.

Comment: No it doesn't , at least on my machine. How are you entering eof?

Comment: This is the same as reading from a file. The op most likely wants to make a basic interactive console program. How does providing input via echo make sense in the case of wrong input?

Comment: The standard i/o streams behave like file streams, that's how Unix was designed (and C and then C++ copied that behaviour). So you are trying to say "we shouldn't worry about this bug because nobody will ever do that" ?

Comment: I am saying that this is an interactive console program, not meant to be used with echo.

Comment: well... OpenSSL wasn't meant to be used by requesting hundreds of bytes in a heartbeat response either.

Answer (score 0):

For one, if you put a "`!`" before a condition in an `if` statement. That's supposed to be a "not" operator.