# Infinite loop when using exceptions in c++11

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, gnu

I would like to create a c++11 program that takes in 10 positive integers and gives the user the total. In the event of a negative number or a char input, the exception should be thrown and the user must re enter their value.

The program below works with negative numbers. However, when I enter a character like "a", the program goes into an infinite loop and I cannot figure out why.

Any and all help will be appreciated

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    int array[10] = {0};
    int total = 0;

    for(int i =0; i < 10; i++){
        std::cout<<"Number "<< i+1 << ": " <<std::endl;
        std::cin >> array[i];
        try{       
            if(array[i] < 0 || std::cin.fail())
                throw(array[i]);
        }
        catch(int a){
            std::cout<< a <<" is not a positive number! "<<std::endl;
            i-=1; // to go back to the previous position in array
        }
    }
    for(int k = 0; k < 10; k++)
        total+=array[k];

    std::cout<<"Total: " <<total<<std::endl;
}
```

Comment: When you type a character instead of number, will be the catch line reached?

Comment: yes the error message is printed, but its an infinite loop. if a number is entered, the program works as expected.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ if(!cin) causes loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23716364/c-ifcin-causes-loop)

Comment: The program goes into an infinite loop on entering a letter because `cin >> array[i]` stops when it encounters a letter, does not change `array[i]`, causes `cin.fail()` to return `true`, AND leaves the letter in the stream buffer to be read next time around the loop.    Try reading data as a `std::string`, parse that string to determine if an integral value has been entered, and discard anything else (like letters).   The usage of exceptions has NOTHING to do with the problem. Aside:   throwing exception is not necessary, since you're catching the exception in the same function that throws it.

Answer (score 0):

If you get invalid input there are two things to thing you need to do:

1. Clear the stream status. This is done using the [`clear`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear) function.
2. Remove the invalid input from the buffer. This is usually done using the [`ignore`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) function.

---

As for your program, you don't need exceptions here, just using *unsigned* integers and checking the status is enough:

```
unsigned int array[10] = { 0 };

...

if (!(std::cin >> array[i])
{
    std::cout << "Please input only non-negative integers.\n";

    // First clear the stream status
    std::cin.clear();

    // Then skip the bad input
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');

    // Make sure the index isn't increased
    --i;
}
```

---

To use exceptions similar to what you do now, the solution is almost exactly the same as above:

```
unsigned int array[10] = { 0 };

...

if (!(std::cin >> array[i])
{
    throw i;
}
catch (int current_index)
{
    std::cout << "The input for number " << current_index + 1 << " was incorrect.\n";
    std::cout << "Please input only non-negative integers.\n";

    // First clear the stream status
    std::cin.clear();

    // Then skip the bad input
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');

    // Make sure the index isn't increased
    --i;
}
```

Comment: thank you, but its a programming assignment about exceptions, and exceptions must be used to handle wrong inputs.

Comment: @Noob_Programmer Then my answer should still help you. Use `unsigned int`, use `clear`, and use `ignore`.

Comment: I tried what you said. Still seems to be an infinite loop unfortunately. Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: @Noob_Programmer Then update your question with your latest code. `clear()` and `ignore()` are part of the answer but obviously you have something else wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget to include limits header file while using following line in your code :

std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits::max(), '\n');

because numeric_limits template is defined in this header file !